# Exclude pattern not working for rsync

Tags: rsync

The following command is working correctly for copying only files matching Mem*

```
rsync -uvma '--include=*/' '--include=**/Mem*' 
'--exclude=*' ../srcdir/ /targdir
```

I would like to also exclude a certain pattern `*.class`. Here is the attempted addition:

```
   '--exclude=**/*.class'
```

And the full command is

```
rsync -uvma '--include=*/' '--include=**/Mem*' 
'--exclude=*' '--exclude=**/*.class' ../srcdir/ /targdir
```

The addition has no effect. The command does copy *.class files:

```
./target/classes/com/blazedb/sparkperf/MemBattery$$anonfun$3.class
./target/classes/com/blazedb/sparkperf/MemBattery$$anonfun$4.class
./target/classes/com/blazedb/sparkperf/MemBattery$$anonfun$5.class
./target/classes/com/blazedb/sparkperf/MemBattery$$anonfun$6.class
./target/classes/com/blazedb/sparkperf/MemBattery.class

 sent 67536 bytes  received 510 bytes  136092.00 bytes/sec
 total size is 67080  speedup is 0.99
```

So then how should that exclude pattern be formed?

Comment: The first matching rule applies so all `Mem*` files are included. Exclude `Mem*.class` first e.g. `rsync -uvma '--include=*/' '--exclude=**/Mem*.class' '--include=**/Mem*' '--exclude=*' ../srcdir/ /targdir`

Comment: Note that `--exclude=**/Mem*.class` is better written as `--exclude=Mem*.class`; same goed for `--include=**/Mem*` which should be `--include=Mem*`.